# Can't get the math behind RSA encryption to work

Tags: math, encryption, rsa

I get tested on this next week, and I was running through some basic examples with prime numbers. The examples in the book don't seem to suffer this problem

STEP ONE- Choose two prime numbers (I picked p=3, q=7)

STEP TWO- Compute n=pq = 21

STEP THREE- Compute totient(n) = tot(p)*tot(q) = 2*6 = 12

STEP FOUR- Choose e such that 1 < e < tot(n) such that gcd(e,tot(n))=1 (are coprime). I chose e=5.

STEP FIVE- Choose d such that d*e % tot(n) = 1.

From what I understood, d had to be an integer. Is that the wrong conclusion? Or is 5 just not a valid e for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has to be an integer. What step five is looking for is the [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). Basically, `d` is the integer such that `d*e = m*tot(n) + 1` for some integer `m`, or put another way, `d*e` is one more than a multiple of `tot(n)`. As long as `e` and `tot(n)` are coprime, `e` will have an inverse — in the case of your example, `d` happens to be 5: `d*e = 5*5 = 25 = 2*tot(n) + 1`.

Comment: I forget modular continues going after the first cutoff sometime, I was looking for 5*d=13 (not considering the rest). Also I made a foobar when I said gcd(5,12)=1 because it's 3. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *d* is an integer, calculated as the modular inverse of *e*. Here is a function to compute the inverse of a number *x* with respect to modulus *m*:

```
function inverse(x, m)
    a, b, u := 0, m, 1
    while x > 0
        q := b // m
        x, a, b, u := b % x, u, x, a - q * u
    if b == 1 return a % m
    error "must be coprime"
```

If you want to see more, I have an example RSA calculation at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/11/16/rsa-cryptography/).